# Consulta para obtener las nacionalidades que han supuesto más dinero

Tags: sql

El enunciado es el siguiente:

> Tenemos un congreso científico (por ejemplo, de matemáticas)
>   organizado por 2 sociedades (las sociedades matemáticas española y
>   brasileña, por ejemplo) con las siguientes características:
>
> - El congreso se celebra en un sólo día y hay 4 sesiones especiales (sobre 4 temas distintos).
> - Cada sesión ocupa una mañana o una tarde.
> - Se utilizan 2 aulas.
> - Hay al menos una charla en cada sesión y a lo más 3, y asisten a cada sesión al menos 5 personas (que pueden asistir a más de una
>     charla de esa sesión).
> - Cada sesión es organizada por al menos una persona y por 2 como máximo.
> - Hay al menos 10 personas registradas en el congreso (que son todos los que participan en el congreso: organizando alguna sesión especial,
>     dando alguna charla o simplemente asistiendo a las charlas); de estas
>     personas, al menos 7 son socios de alguna de las sociedades
>     organizadoras.
> - Al menos 2 personas registradas no dan charla ni organizan una sesión.
> - Los socios de alguna de las sociedades organizadoras pagan 160 euros y los no socios pagan 180 euros.
>
> Crea un fichero congreso.sql creando las tablas necesarias, inserte
>   datos a las tablas y luego me pide que realice las búsquedas que he
>   puesto abajo.

Las tablas que he creado llevan estos datos.

- `REGISTRADOS`: nombre, universidad, nacionalidad, email
- `SOCIOS`: email, sociedad (de la que son socios)
- `SESIONES`: nombre, número, organizador
- `AULAS`: código, capacidad
- `CHARLAS`: título, número de sesión especial, hora inicio, hora fin, código aula
- `PAGOS`: email, precio, forma de pago (trasferencia, paypal, tarjeta bancaria)
- `ASISTENTES`: email, título de charla

Al realizar las búsquedas que tengo abajo he intentado de todo y no me sale. Por favor dadme alguna idea de como hacerlo.

Quiero obtener las "Nacionalidades que han supuesto más dinero por pagos":

```
create temp view t7 as select nacionalidad from registrados union all select precio from pagos;

select * from t7;
```

Primero intenté esto para tener las nacionalidades y los precios en 2 columnas pero solo salen en una los datos unos debajo de otros, luego intenté hacer esto:

```
create temp view t7 as select nacionalidad,precio from registrados,pagos;
select * from t7;
```

Pero me hace el producto cartesiano. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

También necesito saber las "Capacidades de las aulas con mayor número de asistentes que hayan pagado con trasferencia".

Comment: podrías poner las relaciones de las tablas? Se intuyen pero para revisarlo conforme te indica el ejercicio

Comment: por qué creas una tabla temporal? Te lo indica el ejercicio?

Comment: no no me lo indica pero la cree para ver mejor los datos

Comment: por partes, te aparece producto cartesiano en la segunda query porque no tienes relaciónes en las tablas. Tienes el enunciado del ejercicio?

Comment: ya leyendo el enunciado se entiende que necesitas las relaciones, te preparo una solución

Comment: @DulceSeguraAlvarez espero haberte arrojado algo de luz

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema reside en el modelo de datos. Te adjunto una herramienta bastante útil donde puedes visualizar la estructura que vayas creando:
https://dbdiagram.io/d

De modo que te adjunto las tablas/relaciones que considero para que a partir de aquí, puedas insertar e intentar de nuevo las consultas que necesitas, si tienes problemas para añadir registros y/o en hacer las consultas lo comentamos.

https://dbdiagram.io/d/5c38807f687837001457017f

```
 // sociedades matemáticas española y brasileña
Table sociedad {
  id_sociedad int PK
  so_nombre varchar
}

Table socio {
  id_socio int PK
  s_nombre varchar
  id_sociedad int
}

Ref: socio.id_sociedad > sociedad.id_sociedad

Table congreso {
  id_congreso int PK
  co_nombre varchar
}

// mañana/tarde
Table horario {
  id_horario int PK
  ho_nombre varchar
}

// 2 aulas
Table aula {
  id_aula int PK
  au_nombre varchar
}

// 4 temas distintos
Table tema {
  id_tema int PK
  te_nobre varchar
  te_descripcion varchar
  id_congreso int
}

Ref: tema.id_congreso > congreso.id_congreso

// 4 sesiones (1 charla/sesion) -> 4 temas distintos
Table sesion {
  id_sesion int PK
  se_nombre varchar
  id_congreso int,
  id_horario int
  id_aula int
  id_tema int
}

Ref: sesion.id_congreso > congreso.id_congreso
Ref: sesion.id_horario > horario.id_horario
Ref: sesion.id_aula > aula.id_aula
Ref: sesion.id_tema > tema.id_tema

Table organizador {
  id_organizador int PK
  or_nombre varchar
}

Table sesion_organizador {
  id_sesion_organizador int PK
  id_sesion int 
  id_organizador int 
}

Ref: sesion_organizador.id_sesion > sesion.id_sesion
Ref: sesion_organizador.id_organizador > organizador.id_organizador

Table asistente {
  id_asistente int PK
  as_nombre varchar
  id_socio int
}

Ref: asistente.id_socio > socio.id_socio

Table sesion_asistente {
  id_sesion_asistente int PK
  id_sesion int 
  id_asistente int PK
}

Ref: sesion_asistente.id_sesion > sesion.id_sesion
Ref: sesion_asistente.id_asistente > asistente.id_asistente
```

Aqui la imagen de las relaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si bien esta respuesta puede ayudar en la pregunta, creo que poner solo enlaces la hace ver de baja calidad; la idea de SO en español es que aquí se la fuente de consulta de datos, por que si esos enlaces que pones se pierden después entonces otros usuarios que lleguen con esa pregunta no lo van a poder consultar

Comment: es un enlace a una herramienta de un código desarrollado por mi que considero que para no plasmar todo el código aquí y adjuntar imagen, pueda verlo directamente

Comment: los enlaces se pueden quedar pero este espacio usalo para poner también la respuesta, si es necesario que lo pongas para que tu aporte se considere como válido